# Android Provider AlarmClock

Tags: android

I have a MainActivity that start another Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent( AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 10);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 10);
i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);

mContext.startActivity(i);
```

When I run it, the screen didn't change, but a new alarm is set(10:10 am). The screen still shows the activity_main.xml, but I can't use any button or text box in it.

Is there any way I can go back and control the main activity right after the alarm is set?

Comment: call `finish` in the activity that processes your intent.

Comment: try pressing back button once and then using controls. let us know what happen.

Comment: I press back serveral time , nothing happened. Then suddenly it show the menu , I cant open the app and the alarm clock now , but I can open other like facebook and camera...

Comment: I did call finish , but nothing change

Comment: What happens if you omit the `i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_SKIP_UI, true);`?